# Isometric embedding of Schwarzschild metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading through this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4256  about the special case of the positive mass theorem in general relativity. I do not understand the section below:

[image]

In particular what does it mean to isometrically embed an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ in a higher dimensional space, and where does the embedding given for the  $n=3$ Schwarzschild metric come from? I assume we are referring to the standard definition of isometric embeddings using pullbacks of covariant tensor fields.

I assume the author refers to the map between Riemannian manifolds $f: \mathbb{R}^3-B_{2m}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,\sqrt{8m(r-2m)})$. I have tried to check if the Schwarzschild metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the pullback of the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, however this doesn't appear to be true...

Comment: No, there are no reason why the $x,y,z$ in $(x,y,z,w)$ coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^4$ should be the same as the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under some isometric embedding.

Comment: @user10354138 do you understand then what map $f$ the author is referring to and why it realizes a pullback from the flat metric in R^4 to the Schwarzschild metric on R3?

Comment: I think this can be done using spherical coordinates. If $d\theta^2$ is the standard $2$-sphere metric and $dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2$ the corresponding flat metric, then the conformal metric is $$\left(1+\frac{m}{2r}\right)^4(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$$
On the other hand, if we set $w = \sqrt{8m(r-2m)}$, then the pullback of the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $$ ds^2 + s^2d\theta^2 + dw^2,$$ where $s^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.
If you calculate $dw$ in terms of $s$ and $ds$ and compare the two forms of the same metric, you should be able to figure out the formula for $s$ in terms of $r$ or vice versa.

Comment: The $r$ in the formula for $w$ should be an $s$.